# Delete object from array using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, express

I have an API call to get all the users of my application. I have a problem, that the getAll method returns each users's password encrypted. I don't want to return the password.

That's my method:

```
async getAll(pagination) {
    try {
      const { UserAdmin: userAdminSchema } = this.getSchemas();
      let usersAdmins = await userAdminSchema.paginate({}, {
        sort: { created: 'desc' },
        limit: pagination.limit ? parseInt(pagination.limit) : 10,
        page: pagination.page ? parseInt(pagination.page) + 1 : 1,
      });
      if (!usersAdmins) {
        throw new errors.NotFound('No UserAdmins found.');
      }
      usersAdmins.docs.map(async (u) => {
        delete u.password;
      });
      return usersAdmins
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "roles": [
        "Admin",
        "Read",
        "Modify",
      ],
      "_id": "5ffecc12a687a30580239a10",
      "name": "john",
      "email": "john@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$K6oKiiWKsIWmAGgkG7TmH.WjVpraNg45Uc0nber3FnF26oEzdgTS2",
      "created": "2021-01-13T10:31:46.982Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "roles": [
        "Read"
      ],
      "_id": "5ffea1f1dd60b80718af6e3b",
      "name": "Megan",
      "email": "megan@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$V8ARIjxhEHCC1COcvtQEmOZ3IfXm5oiANdLmyHyipy1GmWSD3ctWK",
      "created": "2021-01-13T07:32:01.665Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
  ],
  "totalDocs": 2,
  "limit": 10,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagingCounter": 1,
  "hasPrevPage": false,
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "prevPage": 1,
  "nextPage": null
}
```

I just want to the delete the password. How I can achieve this? The map I have done, still returns the password:

```
 usersAdmins.docs.map(async (u) => {
     delete u.password;
 });
```

Comment: JS map returns new array - the original array does not change. You need to store the result of the Map and return that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a new object in map and return that, or set the password to the empty string with Object.assign

```js
const data = [{
    "roles": [
      "Admin",
      "Read",
      "Modify",
    ],
    "_id": "5ffecc12a687a30580239a10",
    "name": "john",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$K6oKiiWKsIWmAGgkG7TmH.WjVpraNg45Uc0nber3FnF26oEzdgTS2",
    "created": "2021-01-13T10:31:46.982Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "roles": [
      "Read"
    ],
    "_id": "5ffea1f1dd60b80718af6e3b",
    "name": "Megan",
    "email": "megan@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$V8ARIjxhEHCC1COcvtQEmOZ3IfXm5oiANdLmyHyipy1GmWSD3ctWK",
    "created": "2021-01-13T07:32:01.665Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
];

const dataWithOutPassword = data.map((user) => {
  return {
    roles: user.roles,
    _id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    created: user.created
  }
});

console.log(dataWithOutPassword);

const dataWithOutPassword2 = data.map((user) => {
  return Object.assign({}, user, {
    password: ''
  })
});

console.log(dataWithOutPassword2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the objects in your array are immutable, which is why your code didn't work.¹

Instead, create and return a new object, and use the array that `map` returns:

```
return {
    ...usersAdmins,
    docs: usersAdmins.docs.map(
        u => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(u).filter(([key]) => key !== "password"))
    )
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const usersAdmins = {
    "docs": [
        {
            "roles": [
                "Admin",
                "Read",
                "Modify",
            ],
            "_id": "5ffecc12a687a30580239a10",
            "name": "john",
            "email": "john@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$K6oKiiWKsIWmAGgkG7TmH.WjVpraNg45Uc0nber3FnF26oEzdgTS2",
            "created": "2021-01-13T10:31:46.982Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "roles": [
                "Read"
            ],
            "_id": "5ffea1f1dd60b80718af6e3b",
            "name": "Megan",
            "email": "megan@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$V8ARIjxhEHCC1COcvtQEmOZ3IfXm5oiANdLmyHyipy1GmWSD3ctWK",
            "created": "2021-01-13T07:32:01.665Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
    ],
    "totalDocs": 2,
    "limit": 10,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pagingCounter": 1,
    "hasPrevPage": false,
    "hasNextPage": false,
    "prevPage": 1,
    "nextPage": null
};
const result = {
    ...usersAdmins,
    docs: usersAdmins.docs.map(
        u => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(u).filter(([key]) => key !== "password"))
    )
};
console.log(result);
```

---

¹ Re your original code:

1. The `async` is pointless, none of the code in your callback is using `await` (nor does it need to)
2. using `map` but not using the array it creates is an anti-pattern. If you don't need the result array, use `forEach` or a `for-of` loop or just a `for` loop. (But here I suspect we *do* need to use the array that `map` produces.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mongoose lib for model User, declare the password field like this would solve your problem.

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a name']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
        unique: true,
        match: [
            /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
            'Please add a valid email'
        ]
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['user', 'publisher'],
        default: 'user'
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
        minlength: 6,
        select: false // <=== IMPORTANT
    }
});
```

It means that password would not be returned whenever you get Users.

Answer (score 0):

in paginate function you can select every fields that you need with `select` property, like following code:

```
await userAdminSchema.paginate({}, {
       select: "name email",
        sort: { created: 'desc' },
        limit: pagination.limit ? parseInt(pagination.limit) : 10,
        page: pagination.page ? parseInt(pagination.page) + 1 : 1,
      });
```